# Book about a floating city with advanced technology

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I'm looking for a book of which I do not remember the author or title.

The details is that it features multiple characters perspectives, all centered around an advanced city floating in the ocean.

One of the characters is a young man who experiences things in virtual reality and has people watch from his perspective for entertainment.

Another character is a stock trader who somehow accelerates his mind in order to escape death that is coming for him.

A common theme in the book is something related to a technology that lets you split your mind into multiple copies or accelerate your thinking, at the risk of burning you out or something like this.

It might be a collection of dystopian short stories, but I can't be sure because I don't think I finished it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Answer (score 3):

The details of a floating city, multiple characters' perspectives, and one of the characters experiencing virtual reality suggest to me that this could be *[Lucifer's Dragon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11895)* by [Jon Courtenay Grimwood](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?897), published in 1998. The most detailed summary that I could find was on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0743478274/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i5):

> Passion di Orchi is no more than the obscenely rich daughter of a West Coast mafia boss - until she decides to rebuild Venice. In the middle of the Pacific. A century later, with New Venice ossified into a puritanical elegance, the daughter of Count Ryuchi slips away from her father's palazzo, out to the levels to play Lucifer's Dragon. A multi-level, self-perpetuating, true 3-D trawl through the Apocalypse, Lucifer's Dragon is coded so the game never repeats its own failures. But an altercation in a bar puts Karo on a collision course with NVPD officer Angeli, drafted in by media giant CySat to investigate a murder she knows way too much about. And then there's Razz, the silver exotic. Too tired and jaded to keep living, she takes on the job of guarding CySat's ultimate boss, the ten-year-old Aurelio. With all the high tech security in place, it should be a walk in the park. But the last thing Razz sees is CySat's child-ruler making too close an acquaintance with an Uzi, and then she wakes up in Zurich. Dead…